# How to specify a path to be followed while animating an object in HTML using CSS, JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a requirement to move an object when clicked to a specific location following a circular path.
How can that be achieved using CSS or JQuery.

If it helps you can visit this site and look at it to understand what I am trying to achieve.
When user will click any of the menu items, the menu item will move along circular edge and following that path will replace the innermost circle.  http://8055.in/home

I admit I am not able to frame the question well but please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't need a path, you need sinus and cosinus functions

Comment: @HerrSerker can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is a [circle animation plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ellipse) for jquery - have you tried it?

[Working version of circular animation in jquery](http://www.labs.skengdon.com/animate.ellipse)